# Optimizing results instead of apply; get df values and add to list of items

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, vectorization

Simplifying my big problem into this

I have the following datafarme:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"letter":['A','B','D','E','G','W','G','M','E','Q'],'value':[1,6,4,0,9,7,0,-1,5,3]})
```

[image]

and a list of items (name and value):

```
items = [['John',1],['Mike',8],['Jessica',4]]
```

My goal is to add the letters in the df to the items such that if the value in the df + the value in the 'item' is even - the letters should be added to the name.

So what have I done?

```
for i in items:
    name = i[0]
    v = i[1]
    df['is_even'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x['value']+v)%2==0, axis=1)
    letters = list(df[df['is_even']]['letter'].values)
    i.append(letters)
```

and I get the correct result:

```
['John', 1, ['A', 'G', 'W', 'M', 'E', 'Q']]
['Mike', 8, ['B', 'D', 'E', 'G']]
['Jessica', 4, ['B', 'D', 'E', 'G']]
```

**Problem:** note the df has 10 items (N) and the list is 3 items (M) so there are NxM iterations =30. In the real world I have 50,000 rows and 100 items which makes a whopping 500,000 iterations. Too slow.

Any idea how to improve this.

Comment: You just need to extract letters from df in 2 cases and then append to your item list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using group aggregation and a simple loop for in place modification of `items`.

The solution is `O(n)`:

```
# aggregate the letters according to odd/even values
s = df.groupby(df['value'].mod(2))['letter'].agg(list)
# value
# 0          [B, D, E, G]
# 1    [A, G, W, M, E, Q]
# Name: letter, dtype: object

# update items in place according to odd/even subitem 1
for l in items:
    l.append(s[l[1]%2])

print(items)
```

output:

```
[['John', 1, ['A', 'G', 'W', 'M', 'E', 'Q']],
 ['Mike', 8, ['B', 'D', 'E', 'G']],
 ['Jessica', 4, ['B', 'D', 'E', 'G']]]
```

Comment: thank you. this is brilliant. Question, what if the (x['value']+v)%2 is an outside function (a bit more complicated than mod)?

Comment: The logic remains the same, first compute the value **outside of the loop**, aggregate the letters, then iterate over the list and update. The major issue in you code it that you computed again and again the mod and filtered the dataframe